# Allocating years given weeks/months over multiple years

Tags: excel, date, modeling

I am trying to model dates on an Excel file but cannot allocate years by months or by weeks properly.
Lets see the data.

Here is the raw data. I have the sessions ordered by dates with months and weeks

```
date    month week sessions
8/28/2015   8   35  597
8/27/2015   8   35  1053
8/26/2015   8   35  1135
8/25/2015   8   35  1132
8/24/2015   8   35  1115
8/23/2015   8   35  321
8/22/2015   8   34  442
8/21/2015   8   34  923
8/20/2015   8   34  1189
8/19/2015   8   34  1356
8/18/2015   8   34  1309
```

Here is another sheet with rearranged data. I just transposed the list of the dates and weeks from the previous sheet and extracted the day, month, year from the dates with YEAR(), MONTH() and DAY() functions.

```
Year            2015    2015    2015    2015    2015    2015    2015    2015    2015
Month           8       8       8       8       8       8       8       8       8
Week            35      35      35      35      35      35      34      34      34
Day             28      27      26      25      24      23      22      21      20
Weekday         5       4       3       2       1       7       6       5       4
Date            8/28/2015   8/27/2015   8/26/2015   8/25/2015   8/24/2015   8/23/2015   8/22/2015   8/21/2015   8/20/2015
```

Now my problem:

```
Year            2015    2015    2015    2015    2015    2015   ...   2014
Week            35      34      33      32      31      30     ...   36
```

I would like a week view of my data. A list of unique weeks **per year**. The problem is with the UNIQUE() function, the 35th week (or any other week that exists more than once) of 2015 and 2014 and 2013, etc. become the same. And I don't know how to group the dates by weeks.

The other problem is how to tell Excel that given the week, I want the proper year as with the INDEX/MATCH method, it always gives me 2015 for the 35th week of 2015, 2014, 2013, etc...

Any of you have better Excel skills to handle this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you need it for, I'd use a pivot table.  Take your original data, and add a "Year" column, then create a pivot table.  Put the Year and Month as Columns in the pivot table, then put the sessions as Values.  Change the Sessions settings to "Sum of", and you should get what you need.

Comment: Thanks IBam but I need to use only functions.